# Referencing property of one class in another class?

Tags: c#, object, properties, reference

I have a C# script for a server I am trying to get working and I keep getting the following error:

`CS0120: Line 56: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Server.Items.AgelessHouseDeed.Value.get'`

Here is the code in question:

```
public class AgelessHouseTimer : Timer
{
    private HouseSign sign;
    private int m_Value = AgelessHouseDeed.Value;

    public AgelessHouseTimer( HouseSign h ) : base( TimeSpan.FromDays( m_Value ) )
        {
            sign = h;
            Priority = TimerPriority.OneSecond;
        }

    protected override void OnTick()
        {
        sign.RestrictDecay = false;
    }
}

public class AgelessHouseDeed : Item 
{
    private int m_Value;
        [CommandProperty(AccessLevel.GameMaster)]
        public int Value
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Value;
        }
        }

    [Constructable]
    public AgelessHouseDeed() : base( 0x14F0 )
    {
        Weight = 1.0;
        Hue = 1159;
        LootType = LootType.Blessed;
        Name = "An Ageless House Deed ( 30 Days )";
        m_Value = 30;

    }

    [Constructable]
    public AgelessHouseDeed(int value) : base( 0x14F0 )
    {
        Weight = 1.0;
        Hue = 1159;
        LootType = LootType.Blessed;
        Name = "An Ageless House Deed ( 30 Days )";
        m_Value = value;
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to access the m_Value of the constructable in the timer to set the timer to the appropriate time.

Comment: If property is not static, then you need to create an instance of class to refer property. When trying to get property by class name, you treat it as static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are accessing the `non-static` feilds, you need to create the instance first and then access.

Note : you can only access `static` feilds using `classname` directly.

Try This :

```
private int m_Value = new AgelessHouseDeed().Value;
```

Comment: Is it possible, though, to create the new instance using the argument (if one was given) on the command line, or in this case, in game? in game I would type [add agelesshousedeed 90 (the 90 is what I would need to create the object with).

Comment: you can try this ->`_90=new agelesshousedeed(); _90.Value;` you should addsome character before 90 or any number because instance can not be created with starting digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can access static fields/properties directly by using the class name. But if something is non-static than you need to first create instance of object and then call the field/property. You can read all the details of static classes and members [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).